# I'm trying to simulate a directly mapped cache in java. Any ideas on which data structure to use to represent the cache?

Tags: java, caching, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a directly mapped cache in java.  Any ideas on which data structure to use to represent the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try a Map interface for the reference type and WeakHashMap as the implementation:

```
int initialCapacity = 1024;    
Map<K, V> cache = new WeakHashMap<K, V>(initialCapacity);
```